# How to open a menu in electron js on click of a div

Tags: html, css, electron

I made a custom title bar application and then I gave it a `file` menu also.(electron)

Now I want to open a menu on click of this menu. I want a popup but the popup shouldn't be the standard windows popup for the menus , I want to make that custom too...but crating a new window can become very tedious if it takes too much time.

Most probably I want to instantiate a section , but I have no idea how to do it

**The current situation**

I have a window with a #container div having a #buttons div having 3 #minimize,#maximize,#close each with a span

The #buttons also has 2 divs .menu1 and .menu2 i want these menus to behave like normal menus in windows like the file and edit menu

```
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
        <div id="buttons">
          <div id="file">
            <span class = "menu1">file</span>  
          </div>
          <div id="about_us">
            <span class = "menu2">about..us</span>
          </div>
          <div id="minimize" onclick="min()">
            <span>-</span>
          </div>
          <div id="maximize" onclick="max()">
            <span>+</span>
          </div>
          <div id="close" onclick="uff()">
            <span>&times;</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

The result is
[image]

All the menus and buttons are clickable and have hover colors

Comment: Hi Shaurya, could you tell us what you have tried? Show some code and we can get a better understanding of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @anatolhiman ya ill edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to do something like this:

1. create the popup window in html and css. Use position: absolute; and z-index to get it to overlay the rest of the application.
2. Then hide the popup with a css class of for example `.hide`that sets the popup to `display: none;`.
3. You now need a small piece of javascript to toggle that .hide class. Something like for example a function like this: `const togglePopup = () => document.querySelector('.popup').classList.toggle('hide')`
4. Trigger the togglePopup script with the click on one of your elements:

   const trigger = document.querySelector('#idOrClassOfTriggerElement')

   trigger.addEventListener('click', () => togglePopup()
5. Add a method for closing the popup with the same type of technique – adding an eventlistener to a trigger element (X icon for example) and calling the same toggle function as in #3.

Hope this was somehow what you wanted to achieve.

EDIT: Example code for a popup overlay:

```js
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup')
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.popup-close')
const openBtn = document.querySelector('.open')
const body = document.querySelector('body')

const showPopup = () => {
  popup.classList.add('fade-in')
  body.classList.add('scroll-stop')
}

const hidePopup = () => {
  popup.classList.remove('fade-in')
  popup.classList.add('fade-out')
  body.classList.remove('scroll-stop')
  setTimeout(() => {
    popup.classList.remove('fade-out')
  }, 500)
    body.focus();
}

openBtn.addEventListener('click', showPopup)
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', hidePopup)
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fefefe;
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.popup-inner {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6% 16% 0;
}

.popup-close {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  right: 3%;
  top: 3%;
}

.popup-close::before {
  content: "\00d7";
}

.popup-close:hover::before {
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in;
}

.open {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 44%;
}

.open:hover {
  background: #ffffff18;
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: unset;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

.background {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: olive;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <button class="open">OPEN POPUP</a>
</div>


<!-- Add popup at the bottom of the html document, before </body> -->
<div class="popup" role="dialog" aria-label="Popup">
  <div class="popup-close" role="button" arial-label="Close popup" tabindex="1"></div>
  <div class="popup-inner">
    <h2>This is a popup title</h3>
      <p>Popup content...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats pretty helpfull but one doubt , how do i create the `popup window in html and css` should it be just a div?or something else should be better?

Comment: so just to confirm from you (because it turns out im not that experienced at creating any serious projects) the popup is going to be there all the time but just show up when the file div is clicked?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Unless you create the page in React, Vue or other frontend framework that facilitates lazy loading of components, you need to include everything in the code you send from the server to the client (browser) so that it's ready to be displayed anytime, as you cannot reload the page and request more html from the server when you want to display the popup. That means the html should contain the popup from the get-go, but hidden from view with CSS. You create it with a div yes, I can add some example code to my answer.

Comment: Oh .... ik this is basic but im not that experinced , ill try better next time , btw i ended up implementing the same thing but with more basic functionality